# Benefit of signed SSH user certificates?

Tags: certificates, ssh

I've recently read an article [about using an SSH CA](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu). While I'm understanding why signed *host* keys/certificates are useful, I fail to understand what's the benefit of using signed *user* keys/certificates over just using unsigned user keys.

Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: Why is the usefulness of signed host certs not applicable to users?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's useful so you can grant access to any key signed by that particular CA certificate. For example, you have a server which trusts a CA. You can now allow access to any user by signing their key using the CA without having to add their key to the server itself, which might be impossible (let's say it's an embedded device with read-only storage so any addition to `.ssh/authorized_keys` will be lost on next reboot).

Comment: Furthermore, you can trust other information on the cert as well. For example, your server can use a field in the DN (such as CN or OU) to identify a particular user or group.

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed the point that the user cert is not copied to the target machine (but only to the user's machine).

Comment: …or giving a user access to a huge number of machines accepting the CA, without having to manually go through each and add the key

Comment: @JohnDeters isn't it possible to generate a cert with any values in there?

Comment: @SargeBorsch , it sure is possible!  You have to trust your CA to not issue a cert that has those restricted values unless they've authenticated the client.  And you have to configure your server to accept client certificates signed only by your organization's CA - you can't just authenticate on a random certificate from Let's Encrypt.  But since creating trust is the point of a PKI and a CA, those are solvable problems.

Comment: @JohnDeters: the certificates used by OpenSSH are its own unique format, not the X.509 format that LetsEncrypt or any other 'internet' CA is capable of issuing.

Answer (score 2):

Using signed ssh-keys for users has several benefits:

- The user's public key is not distributed to the servers as ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, that saves a lot of pain.
- ~/.ssh/authorized_keys can not be mis-used by adding other identities to it.
- Access control using public keys can be immutable.
- The signed key can have a time limit (lease)
- The signed key can be assigned a principal (admin account) no need to create extra users, just log sshd VERBOSE for fingerprint
- The signature of the key can enforce restrictions of the options that man (5) authorized_keys lists.
- Signed keys have a revoke method.